# Can you identify from inside a Jenkins pipeline if its the first run of a new branch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to see if a pipeline job is the first run of a newly discovered branch from inside the pipeline itself? If you could get a list of all the runs of a job, maybe you could see if there are 0 previous runs and thereby know it's the first run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `env.BUILD_NUMBER`. `env.BUILD_NUMBER == '1'` if this is the first build.

For newly discovered branches in Multibranch Pipeline (which I assume you use) this will work.

Comment: Or check `currentBuild.previousCompletedBuild != null`, for same result but more reliably. Details I described below as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to fix same issue, and end up with this soultion:

```
when {
  allOf {
    expression { currentBuild.previousCompletedBuild != null }
    not { changeset 'your-project-dir/**' }
  }
}
```

Checking `currentBuild.previousCompletedBuild != null` is better than `env.BUILD_NUMBER == '1'` because if first run will be aborted by some reasons, then next build will have `env.BUILD_NUMBER == '2'` but it will not have changes too.
Checking for `currentBuild.previousCompletedBuild != null` guarantied that before was at least one successful build and we could check changes with it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean to identify the build number from within the Jenkins pipeline, then yes, it can be identified using the pipeline [Global Variable](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) `currentBuild`. This variable may be used to discover information about the currently executing pipeline, with properties such as `currentBuild.result`, `currentBuild.displayName`, etc. You may use the property `currentBuild.id` to know the build number and hence whether it is the first build or not.

You may consult the built-in Global Variable Reference at the URL http://[your-Jenkins-host]/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuildfor for a complete and up-to-date list of properties available on `currentBuild`.

Hope, it helps.