# Jenkins Git Changelog on First Build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins pipeline that triggers downstream jobs based on changes to specific folders. The downstream jobs are not being triggered for first time builds. The Jenkins logs shows: `Warning, empty changelog. Probably because this is the first build.`. How can i make the pipeline to trigger downstream jobs on first build? Here is the jenkinsfile

````
    agent { label 'slave-02'}
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true }

        stages {
            stage('checkoutscm') {
                steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${BRANCH_NAME}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxxx', url: 'https://git.xxxx.com/xxx/xxx.git']]])
                }

            }
            stage('DeployRelease') {
                when {
                    anyOf {
                        changeset "scripts/**"
                        changeset "config/**"
                        }
                    }

                    steps {
                        build job: "/DEVOPS_DUMMY/${BRANCH_NAME}", wait: false
        }
    }

         stage('DDLDelivery') {
                when {
                        changeset "DDL/**"
                    }

                    steps {
                        build job: "/PROD/${BRANCH_NAME}", wait: false
            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: what are the changes for the first build?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151175 - @YuriG. that doesn't matter. Jenkins has an empty changelog on the first build of a pipeline. Jenkins 2.204.3 prints out `Warning, empty changelog. Probably because this is the first build.`  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4162

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which git plugin you're using, but I had the same issue with the bitbucket plugin. Changing the pr discovery strategy from `Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision` to `the current pull request revision` solved it for me.

[image: jenkins bitbucket config]

Comment: This is specific to the bitbucket plugin, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix same issue, and end up with this soultion:

```
when {
  allOf {
    expression { currentBuild.previousCompletedBuild != null }
    not { changeset 'your-project-dir/**' }
  }
}
```

Checking `currentBuild.previousCompletedBuild != null` is better than `env.BUILD_NUMBER == '1'` (could be found on internet too) because if first run will be aborted by some reasons, then next build will have `env.BUILD_NUMBER == '2'` but it will not have changes too. Checking for `currentBuild.previousCompletedBuild != null` guarantied that before was at least one successful build and we could check changes with it.

Answer (score 0):

In Multibranch-pipeline configuration, notice `Shallow Clone` is **not** enabled.

When it is enabled, [git will not download](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) relevant branch previous commits, and it's history log (hence the error "empty changelog").